# libcurl redefinition error while building from source for visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, libcurl, mbedtls

I'm trying to build libcurl from source without using dll for visual studio , but getting redefinition error
[Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD7Yh.png)

```
\curl-7.72.0\lib\share.c(35,20): error C2371: 'curl_share_init': redefinition; different basic types
\curl-7.72.0\include\curl\curl.h(2732): message : see declaration of 'curl_share_init'
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved .
By placing #define BUILDING_LIBCURL when you build libcurl.
Note that this define must only be set when you build libcurl, not for code that *uses* it.